# How can write the psql's function with multiple select statements?

Tags: function, psql

Show the table structure:

```
\d quote
                    Table "public.quote"
 Column |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 date   | date             |           |          | 
 ticker | text             |           |          | 
 open   | numeric(15,2)    |           |          | 
 high   | numeric(15,2)    |           |          | 
 low    | numeric(15,2)    |           |          | 
 close  | numeric(15,2)    |           |          | 
 amount | double precision |           |          | 
 volume | numeric(15,2)    |           |          |
```

I want to get all the price(close) change from `2022-12-30` till `2023-06-27` with a select command:

```
select start_p.ticker,round((end_p.close - start_p.close)/end_p.close,4) as change 
    from start_p,end_p 
    where start_p.ticker=end_p.ticker  and
    start_p.date = '2022-12-30'   and
    end_p.date = '2023-06-27'
    order by change desc;
```

Write it as a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change (stime DATE,etime DATE) 
    RETURNS TABLE (
        ticker TEXT,
        change numeric(6,4)
) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
    select start_p.ticker,round((end_p.close - start_p.close)/end_p.close,4) as change 
        from start_p,end_p 
        where start_p.ticker=end_p.ticker  and
        start_p.date = stime   and
        end_p.date = etime
        order by change desc;         
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

It works fine:

```
\set stime  '2022-12-28'
\set etime  '2023-06-27'
select  * from change(:'stime',:'etime');
```

What about the multiple select query in function creating statement?
The three query statements do the some job as in `RETURN QUERY`'s single select statement,i want to embed them in the function creating statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change (stime DATE,etime DATE) 
    RETURNS TABLE (
        ticker TEXT,
        change numeric(6,4)
) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
        create table start_p as (select date,ticker,close from quote where date=stime);
        create table end_p as (select date,ticker,close from quote where date=etime);
        select start_p.ticker,round((end_p.close - start_p.close)/end_p.close,4) as change 
            from start_p,end_p 
            where start_p.ticker=end_p.ticker
            order by change desc;        
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I got error when to call change2:

```
select  * from change2(:'stime',:'etime');
ERROR:  cannot open CREATE TABLE AS query as cursor
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function change2(date,date) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```